# How are two wifi adapters handled in ubuntu 17.10 by default?

Tags: wireless, usb, 17.10

The PCI wifi card in my laptop is rather underwhelming, and unti I fix it, or get an another one, I decided to use a USB wifi adapter that I found lying around.

And I noticed that I can actually use both at the same time out of the box to connect to the same network.

The question is, what happens if I don't disable the PCI card, which one is used by what? And if one of them fails to connect for some reason, does it switch to the other one? Also is there load balancing by default? That would be awesome.

I'm asking all these, because I can't always carry the USB adapter around, and it would be really convenient if I didn't have to disable the PCI adapter every time I plug the USB one in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Networking, and which packet goes out which interface is called "packet routing". Read `man ip-route`.

"Load-balancing" is hard, and not available out-of-the-box.

Failover can be done with my `net-o-matic` script, https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic.git - Watch for (WiFi) network going down, then do a user-specified thing to fix it.

Comment: Thank you, so if I understand the manual correctly, the routes are created dynamically, so I assume that if one of the interfaces ceases to work/exist, then the route is deleted, and the packets after that are sent through the other one, right? Also, how do I know which application uses which route, and which one has priority?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. When one interface "goes down", nothing changes in the routing (the interface might be up again soon). When "packet routing" is done, "which application sent the packet" information is unavailable. All the routing algorithm knows is the IP address of the destination,  and the system routing table. Applications don't have "routes".  Educate yourself on "packet routing" - google is helpful.

Comment: Alright, thanks, will do that. In the meantime I figured, that the PCI card is so unreliable, I'm better off disabling it altogether, and use only the usb one when I can.